# Performing denodo tasks from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, denodo

I am trying a create a working prototype for performing denodo activities from my Jenkins server.

Steps that i want to perform are :

1. Import a VSQL file from GIT to Denodo from Jenkins.
2. Create a view in Denodo from Jenkins.
3. Run this VSQL file in Denodo from Jenkins.

I am new to Denodo world and i am not sure if Denodo has any APIs for doing this.

Can someone let me know if this is really possible? If so where can i find a solution for this requirement. I tried searching in the internet for last few days, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem why you don't find to much on the web for this is that the files and query language in denodo is called vql not vsql. Try searching for that, you will find a lot there.

Anyways about your problem:
You have two options to work with CI and CD in Denodo. If you use Jenkins and just want to create views based on actions in other systems, e.g. create a base view as soon as a new table is created in the source you can just send the vql create script (containing create wrapper an create view) via jdbc or odbc to the server. For that create a technical user on denodo and load the driver to the jenkins server.
The other option is if you are using Denodo 7 to use the solution manager. There you have a rest API where you can create Revisions, test them on different environments and deploy them. Not sure if you can create a revision based on vql code that comes from Jenkins, but I think this should be possible.